# Vocabulary to describe a great football (soccer) victory

Tags: word-request, idioms, vocabulary

If a soccer team scores 4 goals while its opponent scores only 1 in a match, how can we describe this kind of victory? What idioms and/or soccer jargon are there?

Comment: There's a fine line between jargon and cliché - but "hammering", "drubbing", "landslide", "collapse", "mauling" and many more are used.  Sports writing is full of reporters trying (usually failing) to come up with something new for a situation that's been described a thousand times before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Blow out](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blow_out)* and *[blowout](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blowout)* in British English is slang and means to eat a large meal, throw a large party or burst a tyre. It has no connection to any kind of 'victory'.

'War-like' or fighting terms could all be used, *whipped*, *[beaten](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/beat)*, *[thrashed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thrash)*, *hammered*, etc.

*Resounding victory* is fine.

Others could be 'decisive' victory for the winners, or 'embarrassing' loss for the losers.
Had it been 4-0 rather than 4-1, then it would be termed a '[whitewash](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/whitewash)'.

Comment: There are some in the US who understand it quite well, far better than the English understand cooking. :-)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - tbh, I know far more about cooking than I do about football ;)

Comment: "[Tottenham] was/were thrashed" is something I remember. If a player scores three goals in the same match it's a "hat trick"

Comment: I wonder if cooking and football have any lingo in common...

Comment: Spurs were really on the boil today, they totally burned Chelsea, who never looked to be in the mix at all; chilli-hot vs limp lettuce cold. To say they were underdone would be an under-statement. ;-)

Comment: [**clobber**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/clobber) is another good word

Comment: @Mari-LouA - yes, but a bit 1952, Roy of the Rovers etc ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know much about soccer, but I know that the scores are typically low (1-0, 2-1, etc). If in the world of soccer, 4 is considered a large score, then you could possibly call this a *blowout*:

> - [blowout](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blowout)
>     4 : an easy or one-sided victory
>     (M-W)
> - [blowout](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/blowout)
>     a sports competition in which one side wins by a very large amount:
>     *If the game is a blowout, fans start to leave before it’s over.*
>     (Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 3):

A 4-1 soccer/football game is a **runaway win**.

This phrase can be used in any sport and it is used throughout the world by English-speakers.

Comment: I think this is especially true if the victors were leading 4-0 and the losers got one late goal. On the other hand, if the winners were up 2-1 for most of the match, this might not be quite the right term to use.

Answer (score 1):

You could say it was a

> resounding victory

or in American English:

> whop: (US) Defeat; overcome.
>
> ‘the Astros whopped the New York Mets in Saturday's game’